# How to make the label of ransack checkbox filter clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am building a rails app and I use ransack for search and filtering. In one instance, I use ransack as a checkbox filter. The problem is, a user can only click on the checkbox for the filtering to work. What i want is for the user to be able to click the checkbox label as well and the same filter would apply. This is better for user experience since it may be daunting to always have to click inside of the checkbox. This is the view code for the ransack checkbox filter

```
<h4>Roles</h4>
<% new_roles = [] %>
<%= search_form_for @search, :class => 'filters_click' do |f| %>
  <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
    <% if job.role? %>
    <% new_roles << job.role %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <% new_roles.uniq.each do |new_role| %>
    <div class="styled-input-container">
      <%= check_box_tag('q[role_eq_any][]', new_role) %>
      <%= new_role %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers support this feature that clicking a label will also check the box. It's not something specific to Rails, just to be clear.

The way they do that is to look for labels that target

```
<% new_roles.uniq.each do |new_role| %>
  <div class="styled-input-container">
    <%= check_box_tag('q[role_eq_any][]', new_role) %>
    <%= label_tag dom_id(new_role), new_role %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The `dom_id` helper should generate the `id` in the `label#for` field that matches the `id` of the individual `check_box` ([source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag#1429-Use-dom-id-resource-instance-to-create-the-HTML-id))

Comment: I get this error "undefined method `to_key' for "Marketing":String". Marketing is the first filter in my index

Comment: I have edited the question to show the full code that displays the checkboxes